# Visual Studio C++ - Why does always a console page open in the background?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console-application

Why every time I run my project in Visual Studio, a console page opens in the background? How can I stop it opening?

[image]

Comment: You have chosen a wrong project type when creating the project. You want Windows Application, not Windows Console Application. It's the "Console" part that you are seeing.

Comment: Igor is correct. You can change it in the Subsystem under linker settings I believe.